# Detect when an interface is down/up in Twisted Python

Tags: python, twisted

I am creating a multicast listener using the [Multicast Functionality](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/udp.html#auto4) provided by the Twisted Framework. So far, so good. However, I would like to detect if the interface is not already up when the application is launched (which throws a [MulticastJoinError](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/old-api/twisted.internet.error.MulticastJoinError.html)), and wait for it to be ready in order to subscribe to the group, or in the event that the network goes down unexpectedly, get some sort of notification so I can terminate the execution or handle it in any other way.

```python
class Listener(DatagramProtocol):
   def startProtocol(self):
      try:
          self.transport.joinGroup(MULTICAST_ADDR)
      except MulticastJoinError:
          #handle multicast error


reactor.listenMulticast(conf.PORT, Listener(), listenMultiple=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you don't show code, there is little to really say - but in general, a Python-principle is "It's easier to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission", meaning: try something, if it fails (MulticastJoinError), act accordingly. E.g. redo it n-times before terminating, usually with a sensible wait in between.

Comment: Detecting the an interface state is very OS dependent. Which Os are you targeting?

Comment: I plan to use it only on Linux.